# How to find a remote url for my mongoDB to use in my node.js code?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, url, connection

I have a cluster in mongoDB, and I want to connect to it in my node.js server. For that I need a url, but I can't find the correct form in the mongo site.

the format I'm looking for is:

> "mongodb://remote_url:27017/databasetest"

so I am looking for the 'remote_url' part.

I am new to mongoDB so please help me.

I have already tried to click the 'connect' button and than choosing the 'connect to node.js app', but I get a different format.
(this is what I got):

> "mongodb+srv://user:<'password'>@cluster0-afixn.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"

Comment: Remote URL is 127.0.0.1 if the server is in your computer, or the address IP of the server the mongodb is running in

Comment: So you are trying to access a mongodb server in a server you don't know the IP of. Will be hard mate

Comment: What website do you use to handle your mongodb server ? If you get the main server IP, usually the cluster get opened in other ports. Like 27018, 27019 ... etc. [Look here with mongodb atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/)

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. There is no way to reach this server through localhost or any IP since it is a cloud based cluster. Thanks for the help anyway.